# in frappe erpnext I want to change e-commerce setting for each user is it possible

Tags: erpnext, frappe

I intend to establish multiple branches, and on the homepage, I want to provide a country selection feature. When a user switches the chosen country, the system should dynamically display the currency and stock availability associated with that country.

I'm attempting to modify e-commerce settings such that they update when a user changes their country. However, the desired changes should be specific to that individual user, rather than applying to all users universally.